# swift add two arrays with '[String : CLLocation]'

Tags: xcode

Is it possible and if so how would I add these two arrays together?

```
let ausCities = ["Sydney": CLLocation(latitude: -33.865143, longitude: 151.209900),"Wagga Wagga": CLLocation(latitude: -35.1082, longitude: 147.3598)]

let usaCanadacitiesArray = ["Atlanta": CLLocation(latitude: 33.7490, longitude: 84.3880),"Austin": CLLocation(latitude: 30.2672, longitude: 97.7431),"Baltimore": CLLocation(latitude: 39.3000, longitude: 76.6105)]
```

Answer (score 0):

In spite of the variable name, you're dealing with dictionaries, not arrays.  If you want to combine them, look at the description of merging functions in the Swift standard library.  It gives details about handling duplicate keys.

Example:

```
let allCities = ausCities.merging(usaCanadacitiesArray) { (current, _) in current }
```